# Custom label values for X axis in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Can I set Custom label values for X axis in amcharts js?
Type is xy.

[image]

On X axis I had labels 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50... Need to set 0, 1, 10, 100

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the values into your data provider components, such as...

```
"dataProvider": [
    {
        "category": "0",
        "column-1": 32
    },
    {
        "category": "1"
    },
    {
        "category": "10",
        "column-1": 32
    },
    {
        "category": "100"
    },
    {
        "category": "1000",
        "column-1": 14
    }
];
```

To make the data on the chart start on the axis then ensure the "startOnAxis": true is within your categoryAxis section.

```
"categoryAxis":
{
    "startOnAxis": true
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx it`s work. But I need to set 1st point on Y axist, can I do that? example: prntscr.com/55ms9y

Comment: In your "categoryAxis" section add "startOnAxis":true.  That will shift the chart left slightly to make the left point start on the axis as required.  I have updated the answer above to show what you need to include.